# How can I make gradient background to a text in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Is it possible to make gradient color as a background to some text like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Text in a **Text box** can have a gradient color backgroud. Select the Text box and then click on [Draging tools] Format > [Shape Styles] Shape Fill > Gradient > [Variations] Linear Diagonal - Right to Left (or any of the others).